# Find an intersection line between 2 meshes

Tags: python, computational-geometry, vtk

I am looking to find an intersection line(segments) between 2 meshes in python
I tried this:

```
import pyvista as pv
import vtk

def get_mesh_intersection(mesh1, mesh2):
    '''
    Find the intersection volume between mesh vtk objects
    and return the volume of intersection
    '''
    alg = vtk.vtkBooleanOperationPolyDataFilter()
    alg.SetInputData(0, mesh2)
    alg.SetInputData(1, mesh1)
    alg.SetOperationToIntersection()
    alg.Update()
    intersection = pv.wrap(alg.GetOutput())
    return intersection

intersection = get_mesh_intersection(grid1, grid2)
```

Can I extract from the `intersection` the line? how?
I see that I can get `intersection.volume` `intersection.area` `intersection.points`
Is `intersection.points` is what I am looking for?

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use `vtkIntersectionPolyDataFilter` instead of the boolean operation filter.